# Jquery Ajax Post Object response 400 error code in Razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying Jquery Ajax Post to Razor Page action. I created custom object for post then I'm getting 400 Error Code.

Here is my Class struct:

```cs
public class InsertProductPrice
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public int PKademe11 { get; set; }
    public int PKademe12 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Razor Page Action:

```cs
public IActionResult OnPostSavePrice(InsertProductPrice price)
{
    return new OkResult();      
}
```

And here is my Jquery Code (i tried with '`data: JSON.stringify(price)`' but same result);

```
var url =   `/Supplier/insertProductPrices?handler=SavePrice`;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data:  price,
        //contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    
        },
        success: function (response) {
            
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

and here is my object;

```
var price = {
        "ID": priceArray[index].id,
        "PKademe11": Number(body.children[0].children[4].children[0].value),
        "PKademe12": Number(body.children[0].children[5].children[0].value),
    }; 
//Like this
price = {
        "ID": 100,
        "PKademe11": 0,
        "PKademe12": 0,
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add AntiForgoryToken to header:

View:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

js:

```
var url =   `/Supplier/insertProductPrices?handler=SavePrice`;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data:  price,
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    
        },
        success: function (response) {
            
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: it works first time :). Thaks alot. This problem took my 1 day. Thanx alot again